# Search box to pass value to url without = ? symbol

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, search

I have a website where at the moment, it is possible to search by simply typing a value into the url after /search/ 
For example to search for the word hello, i just use url: www.mywebsite.com/search/hello

So i now want to create a very simple search box to search like that, but i do not want to have = ? inserted into my url

For example at the moment i have code

```
<form action="http://www.mywebsite.com/search/" method="get"><input class="nice_search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search...">
 <input class="nice_submit" type="submit" value="SEARCH"></form>
```

but this is producing urls which look like http://www.mywebsite.com/search?q=hello when i only want http://www.mywebsite.com/search/hello

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use javascript/jquery to do what you want. Simply add the submit event on the form and prevent default. In that event you get the search value and send the user to the new page search/hello. Let me know if you need help gretting started with the code.

Notice the added id="searchForm"

```
<form id="searchForm" action="http://www.mywebsite.com/search/" method="get"><input class="nice_search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search...">
 <input class="nice_submit" type="submit" value="SEARCH"></form>
```

Something like this

```
$('#searchForm').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var search = $('.nice_search').val();
   var url = $(this).attr('action');
   //alert('search='+search+ ' url='+url);
   window.location.href = url+search;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you show an example of the code?

Comment: There I updated, let me know if it works... I used return false instead of the prevent default..

Comment: It works! how to remove the alert?

Comment: lol... maybe remove it haha

Comment: When i remove this line alert('search='+search+ ' url='+url); it no longer works :/

Comment: actually it doesnt work!

Comment: Try it now, I updated the whole js code above.. I set the preventDefault thingy on top...

Comment: So how are you going to deal with chars in the search string you can't pass to a URL like this?

Comment: It works. Thanks alot. I had to change the class .nice_search to something else as there is another element with that class, that was why it was not working. Thanks!!!!

Comment: You're welcome :) .. to keep same class use: var search = $('#searchForm .nice_search').val();

Comment: irt Jorg, you can handle it serverside by preg_replace / str_replace or whatver comes to mind.. But thats another question :P

Comment: @Medda86 no I was thinking the search URL value should be URL encoded or something. There are chars you shouldn't put into a URL like less than signs that users can enter into the search box: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid

Answer (score 2):

mod_rewite, is a better approach than client side:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?q=([^&]+)(&.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^search/$ /%2? [R=301,L]
```

alternative if you care to test:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)$ /search?q=$1 [L]
```

Comment: it ALMOST works. Now it is giving url mywebsite.com/hello - it did not add /search/ to it before the query

Comment: Still does not work. Thanks for your help though- i think i prefer a js solution since the site already has man complex rewrite rules.

Comment: until a user with js disabled turns up ...